# Is my home network being attacked?

Tags: networking, router, firewall, ufw

I started to learn about network security and firewalls. My network is very simple, I have a router (MikroTik) and my laptop is connected to it via WLAN. The router has following (default) firewall configuration:

```
Flags: X - disabled, I - invalid, D - dynamic 
 0  D ;;; special dummy rule to show fasttrack counters
      chain=forward action=passthrough 

 1    ;;; defconf: accept established,related,untracked
      chain=input action=accept connection-state=established,related,untracked 

 2    ;;; defconf: drop invalid
      chain=input action=drop connection-state=invalid 

 3    ;;; defconf: accept ICMP
      chain=input action=accept protocol=icmp 

 4    ;;; defconf: accept to local loopback (for CAPsMAN)
      chain=input action=accept dst-address=127.0.0.1 

 5    ;;; defconf: drop all not coming from LAN
      chain=input action=drop in-interface-list=!LAN 

 6    ;;; defconf: accept in ipsec policy
      chain=forward action=accept ipsec-policy=in,ipsec 

 7    ;;; defconf: accept out ipsec policy
      chain=forward action=accept ipsec-policy=out,ipsec 

 8    ;;; defconf: fasttrack
      chain=forward action=fasttrack-connection connection-state=established,related 

 9    ;;; defconf: accept established,related, untracked
      chain=forward action=accept connection-state=established,related,untracked 

10    ;;; defconf: drop invalid
      chain=forward action=drop connection-state=invalid 

11    ;;; defconf: drop all from WAN not DSTNATed
      chain=forward action=drop connection-state=new connection-nat-state=!dstnat in-interface-list=WAN
```

I now looked into my laptop's `/var/log/syslog` and found out that it was filled with `UFW`'s `BLOCK` entries.

```
Nov  9 15:01:48 user kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp0s20f3 OUT= MAC= SRC=[redacted IPv6] DST=[redacted IPv6] LEN=291 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=126516 PROTO=UDP SPT=37417 DPT=21027 LEN=251 
Nov  9 15:26:48 user kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp0s20f3 OUT= MAC= SRC=[redacted IPv6] DST=[redacted IPv6] LEN=291 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=126516 PROTO=UDP SPT=37417 DPT=21027 LEN=251 
Nov  9 15:30:03 user kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp0s20f3 OUT= MAC=[redacted MAC] SRC=85.145.237.54 DST=[redacted IPv4] LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=47648 WINDOW=510 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
Nov  9 15:30:17 user kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp0s20f3 OUT= MAC=[redacted MAC] SRC=120.29.217.52 DST=[redacted IPv4] LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=38990 WINDOW=11 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0
```

There are from three to twenty entries every hour.
Some of the destination IP addresses are from China, Russia and Belarus and I have not used sites from these countries. Is there something wrong with my routers firewall or is something actively being exploited?
Also, with the current setup, if UFW were to be disabled, would it mean that anyone could try to access my laptop?

Sorry for perhaps a silly question but I got little bit shook-up since I had the impression that the firewall in a router would pretty much handle the job.

Comment: It could be simply port scans, the first stage of an attack. They happen all the time. Hackers run bot networks to do port scans on all ip4 ranges, looking for the most common open ports, and if they find any, they try a known password list to see if they can connect. Its an automated process though and I don't classify this as an actual attack, more like probing.

Comment: Every time I log into my SSH server I get a message of the number of failed login attempts since the last successful login, which is frequently in the 4 digits. It's very possible that you're seeing someone attempting something nefarious

Answer (score 1):

The first two entries, though redacted, seem to me like multicast discovery packets sent by Syncthing. (Hoplimit of 1 is typical for such packets.) If you look closer at the IP addresses that were edited out, they're probably your own address and a multicast group address.

The last two entries are *very* likely to belong to an outbound connection (i.e. made from the computer); they might be Syncthing relay servers or something else. Note that 443 is the source port, while the destination port is random-looking; that's what packets from a webserver look like.

One situation where such packets would be blocked is if the connection was still active when your computer was suspended or something like that, which caused UFW's connection state tracking to forget the connection, whereas the router's firewall continued to track it as active (and therefore allowed the packets through).

(This is strictly about the log entries that were shown in the post and not about the ones from China or Russia that weren't shown.)

Answer (score 1):

According to your post its says

[UFW BLOCK]

That should mean that the firewall blocked it.

I usually get between 200 and 1000 and hour so your rate isn't very high.

There are tons of people doing ports scans which maybe be a prelude to hacking but in themselves are not hacking.

Also there are also people trying to randomly connect to every IP to see if there are any open ports they can attempt to exploit.

Of course these are done via scripting so it is 100% automated at this point.

If you have an open port the open port may later be targeted for further attack.

Port 443 is a standard web server use SSL or more accurately TLS encryption.

Some is just checking to see if your running a web server.

For fun, I have been maintaining a block list for several years and it has over 1 million entries and growing.